# Get the text in a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a swing application where the user inputs a number into two of the three fields, and my application does Pythagoras Theorem on those two numbers, and sets the answer field with the answer. However, the three fields (hypotenuse, short side 1, short side 2) are all returning 0 (shorter side 1 and shorter side 2 are different fields, forgot to add the : there), and 0 is the default value. This is not the case for other windows, this is only the case for the Maths tab. My question is, what is the problem?

Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image]

And here is the code:

***Entry.java***

```
package Entry;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;

import Settings.SettingsLoader;
import Window.ErrorWindow;
import Window.SmallLinkWindow;
import Window.Window;
import Window.WindowEntry;

public class Entry {

    public static JFrame frame;
    public static File file;
    public static JInternalFrame currentframe;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        file = new File("settings.txt");
        frame = new JFrame("GUI_Base");
        JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
        JMenuBar bottom = new JMenuBar();
        SmallLinkWindow[] smallwindows = WindowEntry.getSmallWindows();
        for(int i = 0; i < smallwindows.length; i++){
            SmallLinkWindow window = smallwindows[i];
            JButton button = window.getButton(); //ActionListener already added at this point.
            button.addActionListener(getActionListener(window));
            bottom.add(button);
        }
        List<String> data = readAllData();
        SettingsLoader loader = new SettingsLoader(data);
        loader.obtainSettings();
        Window[] windows = WindowEntry.getAllWindows();
        for(int i = 0; i < windows.length; i++){
            Window window = windows[i];
            JButton item = new JButton(window.getName());
            item.addActionListener(getActionListener(window));
            menu.add(item);
        }
        currentframe = windows[0].getInsideFrame();
        menu.add(getRefresh(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.setSize(2000, 1000);
        frame.add(menu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 5));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        System.out.println("Loaded!");
    }


    private static JButton getRefresh() {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("refresh.png"));
            int type = image.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : image.getType();
            image = resizeImage(image, type, 25, 25);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
            JButton label = new JButton(icon);
            label.addActionListener(getActionListener());
            return label;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static ActionListener getActionListener() {
        return new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.repaint();

            }
            };
    }

    //Copied from http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/
    public static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int type, int width, int height){
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        g.dispose();

        return resizedImage;
        }

    private static ActionListener getActionListener(SmallLinkWindow window) {
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Entry.frame.remove(currentframe);
                JInternalFrame frame = window.getInsideFrame();
                frame.setSize(1400, 925);
                Entry.frame.add(frame);
                currentframe = frame;
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }   
        };
        return listener;
    }

    private static ActionListener getActionListener(Window window) {
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Entry.frame.remove(currentframe);
                JInternalFrame frame = window.getInsideFrame();
                frame.setSize(1400, 925);
                Entry.frame.add(frame);
                currentframe = frame;
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }   
        };
        return listener;
    }

    private static List<String> readAllData() {
        try {
            return Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ErrorWindow.forException(e);
        }
        ErrorWindow.forException(new RuntimeException("Unable to read file!"));
        System.exit(1);
        return null;
    }

}
```

***MathWindow.java***

```
package Window;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import Math.Pythagoras;
import Math.Trig;
import Math.TrigValue;
import Math.TrigonometryException;
import Settings.GUISetting;

public class MathWindow implements Window {

    private Color colour;
    private JSplitPane splitPane;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Maths";
    }

    @Override
    public JInternalFrame getInsideFrame() {
        JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame();
        JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane();
        pane.setDividerLocation(300);   
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(300, 925);
        JButton pyth = new JButton();
        JButton trig = new JButton();
        pyth.setText("Pythagoars theorem");
        trig.setText("Trigonometry");
        pyth.setSize(300, 200);
        trig.setSize(300, 200);
        pyth.addActionListener(getActionListenerForPythagoras());
        trig.addActionListener(getActionListenerForTrignomotry());
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        panel.add(pyth);
        panel.add(trig);
        pane.setLeftComponent(panel);
        splitPane = pane;
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
        return frame;
    }

    private ActionListener getActionListenerForPythagoras() {
        return new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                JPanel overseePanel = new JPanel();
                JTextField hypField = new JTextField();
                JTextField aField = new JTextField();
                JTextField bField = new JTextField();
                JLabel hypLabel = new JLabel();
                JLabel aLabel = new JLabel();
                JLabel bLabel = new JLabel();
                JButton button = new JButton();
                JTextField field = new JTextField();
                hypLabel.setText("Hypotenuse");
                aLabel.setText("Small side 1");
                bLabel.setText("Small side 2");
                hypLabel.setSize(400, hypLabel.getHeight());
                aLabel.setSize(400, aLabel.getHeight());
                bLabel.setSize(400, bLabel.getHeight());
                hypField.setText("0");
                aField.setText("0");
                bField.setText("0");
                hypField.setSize(400, hypLabel.getHeight());
                aField.setSize(400, aLabel.getHeight());
                bField.setSize(400, bLabel.getHeight());
                button.setText("Work it out!");
                button.addActionListener(getActionListenerForPythagorasFinal(hypField.getText(), aField.getText(), bField.getText(), field));
                overseePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
                overseePanel.add(hypLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                overseePanel.add(hypField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                overseePanel.add(aLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                overseePanel.add(aField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                overseePanel.add(bLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                overseePanel.add(bField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                overseePanel.add(button);
                overseePanel.add(field);
                splitPane.setRightComponent(overseePanel);
            }
        };
    }

    protected ActionListener getActionListenerForPythagorasFinal(String hyp, String s1, String s2, JTextField field) {
        return new ActionListener(){

            private Pythagoras p = new Pythagoras();

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Hypotenuse: " + hyp);
                System.out.println("Shorter side 1" + s1);
                System.out.println("Shorter side 2" + s2);
                if(hyp.equals("0")){
                    double a = Double.parseDouble(s1);
                    double b = Double.parseDouble(s2);
                    if(a == 3 && b == 4 || a == 4 && b == 3) System.out.println("The result should be 5!");
                    field.setText(String.valueOf(p.getHypotenuse(a, b)));
                }else if(s1.equals("0")){
                    double c = Double.parseDouble(hyp);
                    double b = Double.parseDouble(s2);
                    field.setText(String.valueOf(p.getShorterSide(b, c)));
                }else if(s2.equals("0")){
                    double c = Double.parseDouble(hyp);
                    double a = Double.parseDouble(s1);
                    field.setText(String.valueOf(p.getShorterSide(a, c)));
                }else throw new IllegalArgumentException("All of the fields have stuff in them!");
            }

        };
    }

    private ActionListener getActionListenerForTrignomotry(){
        return new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JPanel overseePanel = new JPanel();

                JTextField hypField = new JTextField();
                JTextField aField = new JTextField();
                JTextField bField = new JTextField();
                JTextField anField = new JTextField();
                JLabel hypLabel = new JLabel();
                JLabel aLabel = new JLabel();
                JLabel bLabel = new JLabel();
                JLabel anLabel = new JLabel();
                JButton button = new JButton();
                JTextField field = new JTextField();
                hypLabel.setText("Hypotenuse");
                aLabel.setText("Opposite");
                bLabel.setText("Adjacent");
                anLabel.setText("Angle size");
                hypLabel.setSize(400, hypLabel.getHeight());
                aLabel.setSize(400, aLabel.getHeight());
                bLabel.setSize(400, bLabel.getHeight());
                anLabel.setSize(400, anLabel.getHeight());
                hypField.setText("0");
                aField.setText("0");
                bField.setText("0");
                anField.setText("0");
                hypField.setSize(400, hypLabel.getHeight());
                aField.setSize(400, aLabel.getHeight());
                bField.setSize(400, bLabel.getHeight());
                anField.setSize(400, anLabel.getHeight());
                button.setText("Work it out!");
                button.addActionListener(getActionListenerForTrigonomotryFinal(hypField.getText(), aField.getText(), bField.getText(), anField.getText(), field));
                overseePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
                overseePanel.add(hypLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                overseePanel.add(hypField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                overseePanel.add(aLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                overseePanel.add(aField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                overseePanel.add(bLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                overseePanel.add(bField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                overseePanel.add(anLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                overseePanel.add(anField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                overseePanel.add(button);
                overseePanel.add(field);
                splitPane.setRightComponent(overseePanel);
            }

        };
    }
    //a == opposite, b == adjacent
    protected ActionListener getActionListenerForTrigonomotryFinal(String hyp,
            String a, String b, String an, JTextField field) {
            return new ActionListener(){

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Trig trigonometry = new Trig();
                    double value = 0.000;
                    if(an == "0"){

                        if(hyp == "0"){
                            int shorta = Integer.parseInt(a);
                            int shortb = Integer.parseInt(b);
                            try {
                                TrigValue tA = new TrigValue(TrigValue.OPPOSITE, shorta);
                                TrigValue tB = new TrigValue(TrigValue.ADJACENT, shortb);
                                value = trigonometry.getAngleSize(tA, tB);
                            } catch (TrigonometryException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }else if(a == "0"){
                            int hypotenuse = Integer.parseInt(hyp);
                            int shortb = Integer.parseInt(b);
                            try {
                                TrigValue tH = new TrigValue(TrigValue.HYPOTENUSE, hypotenuse);
                                TrigValue tB = new TrigValue(TrigValue.ADJACENT, shortb);
                                value = trigonometry.getAngleSize(tH, tB);
                            } catch (TrigonometryException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }else if(b == "0"){
                            int hypotenuse = Integer.parseInt(hyp);
                            int shorta = Integer.parseInt(a);
                            try {
                                TrigValue tA = new TrigValue(TrigValue.OPPOSITE, shorta);
                                TrigValue tH = new TrigValue(TrigValue.HYPOTENUSE, hypotenuse);
                                value = trigonometry.getAngleSize(tA, tH);
                            } catch (TrigonometryException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }


                    }else{
                        int angle = Integer.parseInt(an);
                        if(angle >= 90) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Angle is bigger than 90");
                        if(hyp.equals("0")){
                            if(a.equals("?")){
                                int shortb = Integer.parseInt(b);
                                try {
                                    TrigValue tB = new TrigValue(TrigValue.ADJACENT, shortb);
                                    TrigValue tA = new TrigValue(TrigValue.OPPOSITE);
                                    value = trigonometry.getSideLength(tB, angle, tA);
                                } catch (TrigonometryException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }else if(b.equals("?")){
                                int shorta = Integer.parseInt(a);
                                try {
                                    TrigValue tB = new TrigValue(TrigValue.ADJACENT);
                                    TrigValue tA = new TrigValue(TrigValue.OPPOSITE, shorta);
                                    value = trigonometry.getSideLength(tA, angle, tB);
                                } catch (TrigonometryException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }else throw new IllegalArgumentException("We already know what we want to know.");
                        }else if(a.equals("0")){
                            if(hyp.equals("?")){
                                int shortb = Integer.parseInt(b);
                                try {
                                    TrigValue tB = new TrigValue(TrigValue.ADJACENT, shortb);
                                    TrigValue tH = new TrigValue(TrigValue.HYPOTENUSE);
                                    value = trigonometry.getSideLength(tB, angle, tH);
                                } catch (TrigonometryException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }else if(b.equals("?")){
                                int h = Integer.parseInt(hyp);
                                try {
                                    TrigValue tB = new TrigValue(TrigValue.ADJACENT);
                                    TrigValue tH = new TrigValue(TrigValue.HYPOTENUSE, h);
                                    value = trigonometry.getSideLength(tH, angle, tB);
                                } catch (TrigonometryException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }else throw new IllegalArgumentException("We already know what we want to know.");

                        }else if(b.equals("0")){
                            if(hyp.equals("?")){
                                int shorta = Integer.parseInt(a);
                                try {
                                    TrigValue tA = new TrigValue(TrigValue.OPPOSITE, shorta);
                                    TrigValue tH = new TrigValue(TrigValue.HYPOTENUSE);
                                    value = trigonometry.getSideLength(tA, angle, tH);
                                } catch (TrigonometryException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }else if(a.equals("?")){
                                int h = Integer.parseInt(hyp);
                                try {
                                    TrigValue tA = new TrigValue(TrigValue.OPPOSITE);
                                    TrigValue tH = new TrigValue(TrigValue.HYPOTENUSE, h);
                                    value = trigonometry.getSideLength(tH, angle, tA);
                                } catch (TrigonometryException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    field.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                }

            };
    }

    @Override
    public GUISetting[] getSettings() {
        GUISetting setting = new GUISetting("Show working", "Maths");
        GUISetting setting2 = new GUISetting("Round", "Maths");
        return new GUISetting[]{setting, setting2};
    }

    @Override
    public void setColour(Color c) {
        colour = c;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getCurrentColour() {
        return colour;
    }

}
```

If I need to add anything else please add a comment.

Comment: Please try to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a new instance of `JTextField`, you then pass it's `text` property to the `getActionListenerForPythagorasFinal` method, so it no longer has what "will" be entered into the fields, only what it's initial value is (""), thus it's completely unable to perform the calculation on the fields in question

You could try passing the fields themselves to the method instead, but as a general piece of advice, I would create a custom class which contains the fields and associated actions which you can create whenever you need it, making significantly easier to manage and maintain

Comment: Where the heck have you been? Are you OK?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've moved to the dark side and gone over to iOS development, which, needless to say, has kept me VERY occupied :P

Comment: Congrats on the move, and I'm sure that you'll be quite successful!